# Few characters are showing cross on rotating the text to -90 using iText7

Tags: html, pdf, transform, itext7

I am downloading pdf from html using iText 7.
In my pdf, I have a table header where labels are vertical i.e. bottom to top (by transform -90 deg). When the language is English, every character is printed properly.
When the language is Japanese, Chinese, Czech, Slovakian etc, few characters come as cross. The same labels when printed horizontally come out fine in the pdf. Any suggestions how to resolve this?[Sample table header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bgeC.png)

We have downloaded various fonts of these languages, but still the issue remains.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.